# Ngrok is encountering issues when generating public urls for my project which is running on valet server

Tags: ngrok, laravel-valet

I am trying to use ngrok for my valet project. Whenever ngrok gives me a public url it shows this message. [image]

I am using this command from my project root. `ngrok http http://myproject.test:80`. Can anyone please guide me on what I am doing wrong in here?
Thanks in advance.